# Remove or adapt border of frame of legend using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a plot using matplotlib:

1. How to remove the box of the legend?
2. How to change the color of the border of the legend box?
3. How to remove only the border of the box of the legend?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

When plotting a plot using matplotlib:

How to remove the box of the legend?

```
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

How to change the color of the border of the legend box?

```
leg = plt.legend()
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('b')
```

How to remove only the border of the box of the legend?

```
leg = plt.legend()
leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
```

For the `matplotlib` object oriented approach:

```
axes.legend(frameon=False)

leg = axes.legend()
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('b')
leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could attach the results from each of these options.

Answer (score 39):

One more related question, since it took me forever to find the answer:

**How to make the legend background blank (*i.e.* transparent, not white):**

```
legend = plt.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('none')
```

Warning, you want `'none'` (the string). `None` means the default color instead.

Comment: I think the preferred way to do this is to use `framealpha`, ie `plt.legend(framealpha=0.0)`. That would include the box, though