# How to remove border and resize label title of a geopandas legend

Tags: python, legend, geopandas

So I have the following problem, I want to remove the black border of a colored world map legend in geopandas and resize the label title, but I can't figure out how to do that.

**This is my code:**

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(50, 10))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0, wspace=0.0)

ax=merge.plot(column="counts", legend=True,  missing_kwds= dict(color = "lightgrey"), 
            legend_kwds= {'label': "Medal Count" , 'orientation': "horizontal", 'shrink': 0.2}, ax=ax, cmap='YlOrRd')

ax.set_axis_off()

fig = ax.figure
cb_ax = fig.axes[1] 
cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=15, left=False, labelleft=False, bottom=False)




NaN = mpatches.Patch(color='lightgrey', label='No medals for Gymnastics')
plt.legend(handles=[NaN])
```

**This is what I get:**

[image]

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540259/remove-or-adapt-border-of-frame-of-legend-using-matplotlib

Comment: @PaulH tried it, doesn't work for geopandas color legend, or I might do smth wrong. I have this error if I use that: _No handles with labels found to put in legend._

Answer (score 1):

You must grab the legend's handle for use. The following code snippet shows that the legend's handle, `leg2` is grabbed and used.

```
leg2 = plt.legend(handles=[NaN], 
                  fontsize="large",   # set font size
                  mode="expand",      # allow `bbox_to_anchor` to set position/size
                  bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 0.80, 0.75, 0.2))
# fontsize: 'xx-small', 'x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large', 'xx-large'
# bbox_to_anchor: (x, y, width, height)

# make use of the legend's handle, leg2
leg2.get_frame().set_edgecolor('none')  # remove edge line
```